# A shortcut to select a line in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select all the line your cursor is currently on? In Eclipse? Or even in general on Windows/Linux?

Comment: I know it's late but i know the easy way is  Shift+END(i mean the button end which goes you at the end of the line).

Comment: Eclipse line shortcuts in general: https://javarizon.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/eclipse-line-shortcut/ (and yes it is my old blog)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Solution for Eclipse:**

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>**↑**</kbd> and <kbd>**↓**</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>**↑**</kbd> and <kbd>**↓**</kbd> will move an entire line up or down, so just move it back and you end up with the entire line selected. Thus, the order of <kbd>**↑**</kbd> and <kbd>**↓**</kbd> does not matter.

Comment: Hello, I want to ask what if I am using a MacBook and installed eclipse mac version, therefore I don't have 'alt', what should I press then?

Comment: @TonyChen Use the option key.

Answer (score 31):

What i use is <kbd>Home</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, that will go to the beginning of the line and then select until the end, which effectively selects the whole line. Once you get used to it you can do it really fast. To get a quick view of all current shortcuts you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently using, though I'm searching for something more direct shortcut, since my home - end buttons are really uncomfortable on this keyboard.
Thanks for the list of shortcuts shortcut, that's really useful!

Comment: I use ctrl+d a lot to delete a complete line

Comment: Depending on what your setting is under "General > Editors > Text Editors > Smart caret positioning at line start and end", this will select the _text on the line_ with or without the surrounding whitespace. Either way, note that this is not the same as _the whole line_, because of the carriage return at the end not being selected. This will make a difference when copy/pasta-ing the selection.

Comment: With this setting enabled, pressing the `Home` and `End` keys multiple times will alternate between the actual start/end of line and the 'smart' start/end of line. So when the cursor is at a random location inside the line (except the actual start of the physical line), combination `Home`, `Home`, `Shift`+(`End`, `End`) will select the entire physical line.

Comment: By the way, I prefer this answer to the accepted answer, even if it requires more keys, because it can be reversed (first `End`, then `Home`), and allows the position of the starting point of the selection to be controlled. This way, some `Shift` + `Down` or `Up` arrows can be thrown in-between to select more lines down or up. With the accepted answer, start of the selection is always at the end of the line, thus allowing further lines to be selected only in the upward direction.

Answer (score 17):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to delete the current line, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, that restores the line and selects it.

Answer (score 16):

There is no single *keyboard* shortcut in Eclipse. If using the mouse is not completely ruled out, a triple mouse click selects the line you clicked at.

Answer (score 7):

You can always configure it the way you want in the preferences.

[image: Preferences - select line end]

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem.  It is pointed out later that "select line" does not exist in the preferences... would be nice to have.

Comment: It did solve the problem a month ago, so I do not understand your comment.

Comment: See for yourself in the screenshot, there is no "Select Line" command (ie. select the entirety of whatever line my cursor is on).  There is "Select Line Up", "Select Line Start", etc.  Ie. so there is no simple way to map a hotkey for select line.  (See the comments below for more on the subject.)

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be no command to do that; however, under:

```
window->preferences->keys
```

there are the commands `Cut Line` and `Copy Lines`, which I think is what you need basically.

`Copy Lines` makes a copy of the current line below it and then selects the new line. You can use it in combination with `Cut Line` to move the new line somewhere else.

Comment: I think that holding `alt` and pressing `up` + `down` is easier. (the order of `up` + `down` does not matter - see my answer below).

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is a plugin ([copycutcurrentline](http://code.google.com/p/copycutcurrentline/)) for copying/cutting the whole current line (looks like the author has this problem). It works as following:

> 1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut the whole line in an editor **if you select nothing**. (It works as usual if you select some text.)
> 2. Put the caret on any line on any position.
> 3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the line above. (You will not lose the caret position.)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

For MacOS you can use the combo:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: Or vice-versa, which seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: @arlomedia: Think different ;-)

Answer (score 3):

alt + Shift + Up couple of time will do the trick

Comment: This is the real solution .

Answer (score 2):

1. To select all lines where your cursor is present `ctrl` + `A`.
2. To undo `ctrl` + `Z` .
3. To redo `ctrl` + `Y`.
4. To delete `ctrl` + `D`.
5. To select specific lines `shift` + `↑` /  `↓`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows :

1. Put the cursor at the beginning of this line.
2. Press Shift + Down.
3. Press Shift + Left. (to unselect the extra space at the beginning of the following line - if there is one - )